# PHP: Problems redirecting relative paths with header()

Tags: php

I am doing a project with XAMPP from my university in which they ask me to use the header function to perform redirects and a file structure to follow. But I'm having some problems.
I have the following file structure:

backend/validateSession.php

backend/show.php

index.php

login.html

So, validateSession.php has this inside:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["DNI"])){
$path = "./login.html";
header("location: ".$path);
}
```

And both index.php and show.php have to include validateSession.php

index.php:

```
include_once "./backend/validateSession.php";
```

show.php:

```
include_once "./validateSession.php";
```

When entering index.php, validateSession.php correctly redirects me to login.html

But if I enter from show.php, I have an error because the path is ./login.html instead of ../login.html

So my question is: How could I solve this problem if index.php and show.php need different paths so that header can redirect me correctly? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: header should redirect me to localhost/prog/TP/login.html, but
if i use this path in the header, it probably won't work if someone else tries to access it from their own XAMPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for an HTTP redirect is relative to the *domain*, not to the filesystem (since the browser knows nothing about that). In this case, you should just be able to use

```
$path = "/login.html";
header("location: ".$path);
```

Note the lack of `.` at the start of path. `domain.com/index.php`, `domain.com/backend/show.php` (and any others) will all redirect to `domain.com/login.html`

Comment: Being from localhost and using /login.html, it redirects me to localhost/login.html, generating an error 404. Actually I should redirect to localhost/prog/TP/login.html, which is the path where my project is in the XAMPP directory. Regardless of where you access it, whether from index.php or show.php :(

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realise you were already a few subdirectories deep. Ultimately, the only way to get this to work reliably is to use the full path with the redirect, so `Location: /prog/TP/login.html`.